# How to have number or string as a CLI argument in clap

Tags: rust, clap

I want to have an argument that can be a number or a string. Not sure how to achieve this besides implementing `FromStr` myself. It seems like a simple use-case to handle, not sure what macros to use.
Here, I want the testapp_id to be a number or a string.
I'm aiming for the usage to be like this:
`cargo run -- testapps status 3` or `cargo run -- testapps status app4`

```rust
#[derive(Parser, Debug)]
#[clap(author,version,about)]
enum Submodules {
    #[clap(subcommand)]
    Testapps(TestappsCommands)
}

#[derive(Subcommand, Debug)]
enum TestappsCommands {
    List,
    Status {
        #[clap(flatten)]
        testapp_id: NumberOrString
    },
}

#[derive(Debug)]
enum NumberOrString {
    Number(u32),
    Str(String),
}
```

I was thinking `flatten` is what I could use for this but it's still complaining about missing implementation of `FromStr` .
It works fine if I use only u32 or String type for `testapp_id` , why not both?

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `flatten` for this. Instead you need to implement [`FromStr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/str/trait.FromStr.html) for your enum, e.g.:

```
impl FromStr for NumberOrString {
    type Err = &'static str;    // The actual type doesn't matter since we never error, but it must implement `Display`
    fn from_str(s: &str) -> Result<Self, Self::Err>
    {
        Ok (s.parse::<u32>()
             .map (NumberOrString::Number)
             .unwrap_or_else (|_| NumberOrString::Str (s.to_string())))
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=882ffbbba028f28356278ee90b709d6c)

Answer (score 2):

One common way in Rust of approach the problem it's with the use of generics.
You can make your field's type to accept a generic for that field in particular.

```
#[derive(Subcommand, Debug)]
enum TestappsCommands<T> {
    List,
    Status {
        #[clap(flatten)]
        testapp_id: T
    },
}
```

but this it's not enought. Because you now have a type `T` instead of the `NumberOrString`, which doesn't solve your problem.

I don't know if you design the `NumberOrString` just for the purpose of making the `testapp_id` accept both numbers and strings, but, if you don't need it, you may desire to write some `bounds`.

Bounds are a way of constraint generics over a type `T`, where some restrictions are applied.

Instead of using your enum, you can write this:

```
use std::str::FromStr;

// ... your code...

#[derive(Subcommand, Debug)]
enum TestappsCommands<T: FromStr> {
    List,
    Status {
        #[clap(flatten)]
        testapp_id: T
    },
}
```

and now your field would only contain values of any type `T` that already implements `FromStr`.

Due to your requeriment of accept both numbers or strings, `FromStr` it's already implemented in Rust for all the signed and unsigned variants for a "number".

You can read it better in the docs:
`https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/trait.FromStr.html`

Comment: Generic types are determined at compile time. If I understood the question correctly, it was about allowing the user to call the program with either a number or a string, which can't be accomplished by a generic.